# Running tests in parallel on multiple machines using py.test

Tags: pytest

I know that UI tests can be run in parallel on multiple machines using selenium grid. How about API tests?

I looked at pytest-xdist plugin and it can run tests in parallel on the local machine using py.test -n NUM, which will send tests to multiple CPUs and run them in parallel. This may not be as effective and fast, if the number of tests that we would like to run in parallel is much more than the no of CPUs on the machine. For example: If the machine has 4 CPUs and we would like to run 50 tests in parallel.

And it seems to run the tests on remote machine we need to do something like

```
py.test -d --tx socket=192.168.1.102:8888 --rsyncdir mypkg mypkg
```

I am wondering if there is a way to distribute the tests to multiple remote machines and run them in parallel. For example: If i have 1000 tests and 50 remote machines, then i would like each remote machine to run  1 or more tests at the same time so that tests complete faster. Which means, all the 1000 tests will complete in the time it takes for 20 tests or less.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want the `load` distribution mode, followed by multiple invocations of the `--tx` argument:

```
py.test --dist=load --tx socket=192.168.1.110:8888 --tx socket=192.168.1.111:8888 --tx socket=192.168.1.112:8888 --rsyncdir mypkg mypkg
```

I'm sure you've looked at CPU usage of the python processes when running the tests. If you are doing what what I expect you are doing (running an integration test suite against a single instance of a network service with high response times), your test suite isn't CPU bound but is actually I/O bound. For this type of workload, CPU usage may appear high, but actually includes the amount of time the test runner spent waiting for a response from the system under test.

The biggest problem I've encountered when parallelizing that type of test suite is that the order tests complete sometimes matters, and when run in parallel tests finish in a different order when they run in series just due to variation in response times, causing intermittent and difficult to troubleshoot test failures.

If that doesn't happen with multiple cores on a single machine, that's a good sign your plan will work. That having been said, because there is operational overhead involved with keeping any pool of hosts around - patching with updates, dealing with configuration, provisioning, and networking, not to mention other unexpected issues, I suggest you try something different.

I think you should consider refactoring your test code to use asynchronous IO instead of setting up the test grid. When you do this correctly, multiple tests will be able to run on one core at the same time. Your sysadmin (which may be you!) will thank you.